# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: "nameMyFunction" is not a function in useEffect React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I'm sorry for my English. I'm using a translator. I have the following problem. I'm trying to use a function from another component, but it gives me the following error.

I will leave the code extract:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9xMg.jpg)

I used useEffect to display the data for an id depending if that id has records:

```
export async function getOrderByTableApi(idTable, status= "", ordering= ""){
    try {
        const tableFilter = `table=${idTable}`;
        const statusFilter = `status=${status}`;
        const closeFilter = "close=false";

        const url = `${BASE_API}/api/orders/?${tableFilter}&${statusFilter}&${closeFilter}&${ordering}`;
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const result = await response.json();
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

the function comes from another component as follows:

```
import { getOrderByTableApi } from "../api/orders";

export function useOrder(){
    const [setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [setError] = useState(false);
    const [setOrders] = useState(null);

    const getOrderByTable = async (idTable, status, ordering) => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await getOrderByTableApi(idTable, status, ordering);
        setLoading(false);
        setOrders(response);
      } catch (error) {
        setLoading(false);
        setError(error);
      }
    };

    return{
        getOrderByTable,
    };

}
```

and when using it, the console tells me that getOrderByTable is not a function

```
import { useTables } from "../../hooks";

export function OrdersHistory() {
  const [idTable, setIdTable] = useState(null);
  const { getOrdersByTable } = useOrder();
  const { getTableByNumber } = useTables();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const table = await getTableByNumber(tableNumber);
      const idTableTemp = table[0].id;
      setIdTable(idTableTemp);

      **getOrdersByTable(idTableTemp, "", "ordering=-status,-created_at");**
    })();
  }, []);


  return (
           
          <p>Help please</p>

  );
}
```

adjunto imagen
[image]

Comment: You're missing an `s` of your exported function name in the `useOrder` hook: getOrder**s**ByTable

Comment: Use copy-paste instead of  letter by letter typing is a good habit for coding.

Comment: oh sir, I think that coding all day brings its consequences, I didn't pay attention to that other letter, now everything fits because it is not recognized as a function, yes, next time I will copy and paste the name of the functions, I swear I was I spent all day looking for the error and couldn't find it out of fatigue, it's good to have the vision of a third party in a project, thank you very much for taking the time to review and respond

Answer (score 0):

There is a typing mistake in your code. You're exporting the function as `getOrderByTable` from your custom hook useOrder but you're importing it as `getOrdersByTable` instead of `getOrderByTable` in your OrdersHistory component.

If you want to rename your function, you can do it as below

```
 const { getOrderByTable as getOrdersByTable } = useOrder();
```

Comment: friend, thank you very much for taking the time to review my code, indeed I was missing a letter, I think that fatigue did not let me see it, now it works perfectly, this page is the best there is for programming

Comment: That's what I wrote brother in the paragraph. But I also provided a way for you to rename the function.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the review, due to fatigue I did not notice that the name of the function did not match a letter and that is why it gave me an error, I will take the recommendation to copy and paste the names of the functions in the future, I consider this question closed. Thank you so much.

Comment: This should be in comment and not as an answer

Comment: Sorry, I started interacting with the page recently

Comment: Friend, a question, how can I delete the questions that I have asked in stack?